# Extract part of NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, substring, href

My app gets the string from an RSS feed for the preview image.  It displays in this format:

```
<p><a href="http://316apps.com/LakesideNews/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/144x1443.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-22" title="144x144" src="http://316apps.com/LakesideNews/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/144x1443.png" alt="" width="144" height="144" /></a></p>
```

hi

I am parsing the rss using GDATAXML and tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's blog. I set up an NSString to the value that is given in the RSS for the image. I then set up an NSLog with that string. What the NSLog returns is what I had put in the original post. Is there a way to subString it to get just the part between " "?

Comment: As NTTake meantioned, you just need to parse the XML.

Also it seems as though your "feed" is incorrect format the <a href/> is declared as a single line, but you have the closing bracket in there as well. So it may not parse correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSRange, but you'll need to determine the start point and length (the position of the two quotes)

```
[untested code]

int idStart = 0;
int idEnd = 0;

for (int f = 0; f < [initialString length]; f++) {
    NSRange myRangeStart;
    myRangeStart.location = f;
    myRangeStart.length = 1;
    substr = [urlStr substringWithRange:myRangeStart];
    if ( idStart == 0) {
        if ([substr isEqualToString:@"\""]) {
            idStart = f;
        }
    } else {
        if ([substr isEqualToString:@"\""] && f > idStart) {
            idEnd = f;
        }
    }
}


NSString* substring = @"";
NSRange myRange;
myRange.location = idStart+1;
myRange.length = idEnd-idStart-1;
substring = [initialString substringWithRange:myRange];

[/untested code]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in Apple's documentation. You should be able to use the string as NSData and parse it with that object.

Comment: I am parsing it using GDATAXML and tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's blog.  I set up an NSString to the value that is given in the RSS for the image.  I then set up an NSLog with that string.  What the NSLog returns is what I had put in the original post.  Is there a way to subString it to get just the part between " "?

Comment: Figured it needed to be said, as I am ALREADY parsing the XML, not looking to parse it.